# Check user input against a list of characters

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying to take user input as a string and check it against a list of characters, I want the user to create a word using only characters from the list.

So far I can check that the first letter is correct but any more than that and my test fails!

```
wordInput = str(input("words please: "))
if wordInput in ['w', 'v', 'g']:
print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

I'm not sure how I can take the input and split it so that my test recognizes each individual character of the input rather than testing the input literally against the characters in the list.

Any help would be gratefully received, Thank you

Comment: use a for in loop to go through each letter at a time `for letter in word_input:`

Comment: Don't need to use `str(input(..`, – it already [returns a string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input).

Comment: not too sure why I've been marked down? if you would like to explain I would be more than happy to edit my question

Comment: You could have written this with a simple loop. So far, the answers below use more advanced techniques (more "pythonic") but looping over `word_input` and testing one character at a time is not entirely illogical. (Also, your indentation is bad. Also, you are not testing "that the first letter is correct... it only works on *one* letter inputs.)

Comment: that's kind of why I asked for help?

Comment: Ah – you did not *know* there was a `for` in Python? Check out the [official Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements), "4.2. `for` Statements".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to match all characters against the master list .

```
wordInput = str(input("words please: "))
only_valid_characters = ['w', 'v', 'g']
validatedInput = [valid_char for valid_char in wordInput if valid_char in only_valid_characters]

if len(wordInput) == len(validatedInput):
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, your answer makes perfect sense!

Comment: You can accept the answer if it worked! :-)

Comment: This checks if all valid characters are used, not if all used characters are valid

Comment: It reconstructs the string with used valid characters. Length match is done to make sure everything was valid! I dont know why there was a down vote!

Answer (score 1):

The pythonic way here is to use sets:

```
def validate_input(userword, accepted_chars):
    return set(accepted_chars).issuperset(userword)

def main():
    # input() always returns a string in Py3    
    userword = input("words please:")
    if validate_input(userword, "wvg"):
        print("ok")
    else:
        print("ko")

if __name __ "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: @schwobaseggl oops - you're of course right, my bad

Comment: @schwobaseggl fixed ;-) thx for correcting me.

Answer (score 1):

The pythonic way here is to use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```py
word_input = input("words please: ")
if all(ch in ['w','v','g'] for ch in word_input):
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

`.. for ch in word_input` yields every character in `word_input` one by one. As soon as the test `ch in [..]` fails, `all` will return `False`; if all tests pass, it returns `True`.

Comment: `... ch in 'wvg'...` will look even cleaner.

Comment: @schwobaseggl: that's what I initially had, but OP uses a list. It may be for other reasons. There is no functional difference, so I used that as well.